# How do I update the DB structure via cPanel without losing existing data?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, cpanel, laravel-8, laravel-migrations

I have initially implemented a Laravel project on the cPanel and imported the database. I have updated the local/development database via Laravel Migrations. I want this updated database structure to be reflected on the cPanel, without losing the data already stored on the cPanel database.

How do I update the Laravel DB on the cPanel without losing the existing cPanel data?

Comment: you need to write a migration script for your db , however you should always have a backup

Comment: This shouldn't be any problem with migrations. Of course, if you drop a column, the data is gone. Renaming and adding columns are no problem. Or changing it's properties (from INT to BIGINT for example). Your production version will warn you, you can answer 'yes' or run `php artisan migrate --force` As @eshirvana mentions, make a copy/backup first. Or like I do, in mysqladmin, I copy the affected table(s) to table_name_copy before running the migration.